# Select in Select MySQL

Tags: mysql, multi-select

I have two queries, i'd like if is possible execute in only one query as a Select in Select.

The first one:

```
SELECT
users.id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_date ON users_date.user = users.id
LEFT JOIN users_varchar ON users_varchar.user = users.id
WHERE
abilitato = 1 
AND users_date.key = 'birthday'
AND users_varchar.key = 'nation'
AND users_varchar.value = 'US'
AND (users.reg_date >= '2013-05-31' AND users.reg_date <= '2013-05-31')
AND (floor(DATEDIFF(NOW(), users_date.value) / 365) >= 19 AND floor(DATEDIFF(NOW(), users_date.value) / 365) <= 19)
```

it retrieve a list of user id (filtered by Age, Nation or Date of registration)

the second one:

```
SELECT count(`matches`.`id`) FROM `matches` WHERE (`matches`.`status_home` = 3 AND `matches`.`status_guest` = 3) AND (`matches`.`team_home` = 13 OR `matches`.`team_guest` = 13)
```

i need perform the second select for every ID retrieved by the one's.
for every perform i must replace the value 13 with the id retrieved.

it is possible perform all in a single query with a select in select?

thanks advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql.

```
SELECT count(`matches`.`id`) 
FROM `matches` m
INNER JOIN ( SELECT users.id as id
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_date ON users_date.user = users.id
LEFT JOIN users_varchar ON users_varchar.user = users.id
WHERE abilitato = 1 
AND users_date.key = 'birthday'
AND users_varchar.key = 'nation'
AND users_varchar.value = 'US'
AND (users.reg_date >= '2013-05-31' AND users.reg_date <= '2013-05-31')
AND (floor(DATEDIFF(NOW(), users_date.value) / 365) >= 19 AND floor(DATEDIFF(NOW(), users_date.value) / 365) <= 19)) t
on t.id=m.team_guest
WHERE (`matches`.`status_home` = 3 AND `matches`.`status_guest` = 3) 
AND (`matches`.`team_home` = 13 OR `matches`.`team_guest` = t.id)
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: there is a problem
you suggest an INNER JOIN, but the ON clause is wrong :(
the t.id value could be on team_home field or team_guest field

i must also change the team_home = 13 with a parameter value

Answer (score 0):

You can express what you want to do as an explicit join.  But the question asks for a select within a select.  For that, you need a correlated subquery.  Here is the final query:

```
select users.id,
       (SELECT count(`matches`.`id`)
        FROM `matches`
        WHERE (`matches`.`status_home` = 3 AND `matches`.`status_guest` = 3) AND 
              (`matches`.`team_home` = user.id OR `matches`.`team_guest` = users.id)
       ) as cnt
FROM users LEFT JOIN
     users_date
     ON users_date.user = users.id LEFT JOIN
     users_varchar
     ON users_varchar.user = users.id
WHERE abilitato = 1 AND users_date.key = 'birthday' AND
      users_varchar.key = 'nation' AND users_varchar.value = 'US' AND
      (users.reg_date >= '2013-05-31' AND users.reg_date <= '2013-05-31') AND
      (floor(DATEDIFF(NOW(), users_date.value) / 365) >= 19 AND
       floor(DATEDIFF(NOW(), users_date.value) / 365) <= 19
      )
```

(The formatting helps me understand the query better.)

Doing this without a correlated subquery is a bit challenging because of the `or` in the matching condition.